# Networking and sharing data

Tags: router

I Have a tp_link TL-WR740N router  and two pc and laptop and then...

How Can I Do network two or four computer with one router and use internet and sharing data between ones?

Excuse me for bad grammar's!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest case is when they are all **in the same network segment**.

And that is the case when they are all connected to the same router to the internet.
Hubs or switches somewhere in between are no problem.

The usual default setup is just right for the case - the router should run **DHCP** to tell all connected computers which **common network address**, and **which IP addresses** to use.

Using the router configuration, you can assign **names to the computers**, which will be associated with the **MAC hardware address** of the network interfaces.

The router will assign IP addresses to the computers, but in case the IP addresses get changed later, the router can just map the name to the new IP address.

That should be all you need!

Your internet provider will normally change your IP address seen from the internet from time to time, because it makes thir life easier.

To easily **reach your router from outside interenet** anyway, use a **dynamic DNS** service, that will **keep track of your IP** address and let the iinternet know if someone asks.
(They are usually free of charge or very cheap.)

From the internet, you do not see the individual computers. **There is just the router**. But the router can be configured to forward connections to a certain port to a certain computer, which is called network address translation, NAT. So you can share the connections from outside too.

For example, if Alice and Bob want to run a web server, the can run it on their port 80 both on their computers, and the router gets configured to foreard connections to port 80 to alicesbox:80, and connections to port 8080 to bobsbox:80.